# AttributeError in Python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently working on a Python web scraping project, and I get this error on line 7:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

I made sure every package is installed correctly.

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get("https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/tenday/l/INKA0344:1:IN")
content=page.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
l=[]
all=soup.find("div",{"class":"locations-title ten-day-page-title"}).find("h1").text
 

table=soup.find_all("table",{"class":"twc-table"})
for items in table:
    for i in range(len(items.find_all("tr"))-1):
        d = {}
        try:
            d["day"]=items.find_all("span",{"class":"date-time"})[i].text
            d["date"]=items.find_all("span",{"class":"day-detail"})[i].text         
            d["desc"]=items.find_all("td",{"class":"description"})[i].text
            d["temp"]=items.find_all("td",{"class":"temp"})[i].text
            d["precip"]=items.find_all("td",{"class":"precip"})[i].text
            d["wind"]=items.find_all("td",{"class":"wind"})[i].text
            d["humidity"]=items.find_all("td",{"class":"humidity"})[i].text
        except:
            d["day"]="None"
            d["date"]="None"
            d["desc"]="None"
            d["temp"]="None"
            d["precip"]="None"
            d["wind"]="None"
            d["humidity"]="None"
        #print("")
        l.append(d)

import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(l)
print(df)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: What is your question? If you're sure that `soup` is not `None` then obviously `soup.find("div",{"class":"locations-title ten-day-page-title"})` must be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The following part of your code returns None:

```
soup.find("div",{"class":"locations-title ten-day-page-title"})
```

Then on this None you call a find method e.g.

```
.find("h1").text
```

Hence you get the error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'"

If you press F12 on the browser can you find a div with class name "locations-title ten-day-page-title"?